# Green's function: relation to DOS and analyticity

Tags: field-theory, greens-functions

It is not uncommon to see the (retarded) Green's function being defined in terms of the DOS:
$$ G^R(\omega) := \int \frac{\rho(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon-(\omega+i0^+)} \mathrm d \varepsilon. $$

I just want to make sure I correctly understand this formula. In particular, we are often interested in *complex* energies; e.g. a pole of $G^R(\omega)$ at $\omega = \omega_0 - i\Gamma$ would correspond to a particle with lifetime $\Gamma$. However, if I understand correctly, the above formula should not be directly used for complex $\omega$. Rather, the above gives an expression for $G^R(\omega)$ on the real line ($\omega \in \mathbb R$) which should then be analytically continued onto the complex plane (which is *not* the same as directly using the above formula for $\omega \in \mathbb C$).

Rather, perhaps a clearer definition of $G^R(\omega)$ would be to define 
$$ G^R(\omega) := \int \frac{\rho(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon-\omega} \mathrm d \varepsilon \quad \textrm{ if }\textrm{Im } \omega > 0,$$
and then analytically continue it to the lower complex plane.

To illustrate my point, consider the simple example, the Lorentzian $\rho(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\Gamma}{\omega^2 + \Gamma^2}$. Then it is easy to calculate that
$$ \int \frac{\rho(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon-(\omega+i0^+)} \mathrm d \varepsilon = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{1}{\omega + i \Gamma} & & \textrm{if Im } \omega \geq 0, \\
-\frac{1}{\omega - i \Gamma} & & \textrm{if Im } \omega < 0.
\end{array} \right. $$
Note that this function has no poles (but a branch cut on the real axis). However, given the above discussion, we can conclude that $G^R(\omega) = \frac{1}{(-i\Gamma) - \omega}$ (for any $\omega \in \mathbb C$), which is analytic and has a pole in the lower half-plane (as expected).

(I'm sure that all of the above is trivial to anyone well-versed in Green's functions. The point of this post is just to check whether the above is the 'right' way to think about these things.)

Comment: All you wrote look correct. I suppose you could answer the question yourself, and a significant fraction of your "question" could be moved to the answer.